# Change default layer name in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-2.18

In QGIS 2.18, new vector layers resulting from QGIS tools have a default name related to the corresponding tool. For example, when I perform the "Lines to polygons" operation (under QGIS Vector menu), the resulting layer is always named *Polygons from lines* in the Layers Panel -- even if I ask for the shapefile to be saved under a specific name. When I compute a buffer, the new layer is called *Buffer*, and so on.

If I recall correctly, this was not the case in QGIS 2.14 (and previous versions): the default name of a layer was the name of its shapefile.

I find the new behaviour annoying since it leads to confusion between my layers; every time I use a QGIS tool, I have to uncheck the "Open output file after running algorithm" option, then manually open the newly created layer in order to display its "real" name. I can also change its name in the layer properties, but this is still irritating.

Is there a way to go back to the traditional behaviour? E.g. display by default the shapefile name (when specified) in the Layers Panel instead of some generic name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From QGIS 2.16 vector menu functions using processing toolbox, so this behaviour can be changed in processing options in menu `Processing -> Options...`. In `General` options check the `Use filename as layer name`.

[image]

*QGIS 3 Update:*

The Processing options in QGIS 3 are in main settings `Settings -> Options` in `Processing` tab. Also can be launched directly from processing toolbox - [image] *Options*.

Comment: Great! It should be the default option.

Comment: It seems it has been fixed here: https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/repository/revisions/f1ac0be86769e924624cb87b48e0ef69a0da1387

Comment: Anyone know where this option is in QGIS 3?

Comment: Updated my answer